# Ошибка: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: response.json is not a function"

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Пытаюсь получить данные с БД:

```
export async function Otdel() {
    try {
        const cards = await sequelize.query(
            'select * from sta_otdel',
            {
                type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
            },
        );

        if (!cards) {
            return { success: false, error: ErrorCode.notFound };
        }

        return {
            success: true,
            content: cards,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        return { success: false, error: ErrorCode.unexpectedError };
    }
}


async function tableDocuments(response: Response) {
  const data = await incomingService.tableDocuments.Otdel()
  return response.json(data)
}
```

На клиенте получаю с помощью `axios`:

```
const response = await axios.get(`/incoming/tableDocuments`, {
      headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + User.token },
      cancelToken: tableDocumentsCancelToken.token,
    })

    if (response.data?.success) {
      return {
        type: "ok",
        content: response.data.content,
        info: response.data.info,
      }
    }
```

Почему возникает эта ошибка?

Comment: покажите как вы на **backend** вызываете функцию tableDocuments. что вы передаёте при вызове tableDocuments?

Comment: @nörbörnën на бэке 
```export const path: string = "/incoming";
export const instance: Router = Router();
instance.get("/tableDocuments", tableDocuments)```

Comment: т.е. `tableDocuments` - это функция, которая выполняется при сопоставлении маршрута? какие аргументы у такой функции? https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/basic-routing.html

Comment: @nörbörnën да, и на фронте я с помощью axios по этому маршруту пытаюсь получить данные и если все ок, формируется обьект

Comment: остановись и ответь на вопрос: какие аргументы у функции обрабатывающей запрос (в express)?

Comment: @nörbörnën нет аргументов

Comment: нет. `app.get('/', function(req, res)`

Comment: @nörbörnën не совсем понял, это имеешь в виду? `express().use(express.json()).use("/", router).all("/*", (_, response: Response) => response.status(404).json({ success: false, error: ErrorCode.notFound }))`

Comment: обработчик запроса принимает 2 параметра: request и response. В твоём обработчике принимается первый параметр (request) и используется как response-параметр

Comment: @nörbörnën а понял, а как тогда передать правильно?

Comment: а ты как думаешь?

Comment: @nörbörnën если ты про добавить первым параметром request, то вылетает ошибка, что он никогда не используется, или не в том направлении я понял?

Comment: в этом направлении. ну и пусть не используется.

Comment: @nörbörnën не дает скомпилить проект в таком случае

Comment: @nörbörnën все решил проблему, добавил знак_ перед request: Request и запустило, возвращает теперь норм все. Спасибо огромное за подсказки!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обработчик запроса express принимает 3 параметра: request, response и next function.

В вашем обработчике, функция `tableDocuments`, принимается первый параметр (`request`) и используется как второй параметр (`response`). Это не правильно так как порядок аргументов функции должен быт соблюден!

Судя по коду, ваше приложение написано на [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript), вот краткий пример правильного обработчика:

```
import * as express from 'express';

// Router
const router = express.Router();
const tableDocuments: express.RequestHandler = async (_, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = {ok: true};
    return res.json(data);
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
};
router.get('/', tableDocuments);

// Application
const app = express();

app.use('/tableDocuments', router);

app.listen(3002, 'localhost');
```

<sub>Проверено на node.js v15.0.1, typescript v4.0.5</sub>